# choice of separator ignored by CONCAT_WS (mysql/mariadb)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I may be missing something simple, but it seems that the separator I'm choosing for `CONCAT_WS` doesn't seem to be working when inside a more complex query.

First I tested CONCAT_WS by itself:

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' / ', 'a', 'b', 'c') AS `test`;
```

Which returned:

```
test
a / b / c
```

Then I tried it inside a `GROUP_CONCAT` which I intended to use:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(' / ', 'a', 'b', 'c') ) AS `test`;
```

Which returned:

```
test
a / b / c
```

Okay all good, so I tried it in my proper query on live data:

```
SELECT `Box Barcode`,`Title`,`Start Date`,`End Date`,`Offsite Indicator`,`MIA`,
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(' / ',`Description`) ) AS `Contents` 
FROM `boxes` 
GROUP BY `Box Barcode` ORDER BY `Box Barcode` ASC ;
```

Which returned the correct results, except with commas instead of `/`
For example here's one line of the results:

```
Box Barcode  Title     Start Date  End Date    Offsite Indicator  MIA    Contents
C5500501127  PPS AMEX  30/06/2002  30/06/2002  TRUE               FALSE  PPS AMEX,PPS AMEX,PPS DINERS,PPS DINERS,PPS LIABILITIES,PPS PROPERTY PLAN AND EQUIPMENT,PPS ASSETS
```

A couple hour's of googling have not helped. Anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? This is via a PhpMyAdmin web interface on a Debian server running MariaDB (libmysql - 5.5.53).

Comment: _Your query has a problem_.  You are selecting non aggregate columns which do not appear in `GROUP BY`.  Please update your question with the logic you want for choosing a single record for each barcode.

Comment: Yes @TimBiegeleisen in almost any other SQL you'd need to list them all. But mysql is a bit loose around that particular point. So no "...it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause" error. Mysql is wrong, but it doesn't care. XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be that the `GROUP_CONCAT` also has a separator.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(' / ',`Description`) ) AS `Contents`
```

will result in a `,` separation

this here:

```
GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT_WS(' / ',`Description`) SEPARATOR ' / ')
```

Will make the `GROUP_CONCAT` have `/` separator

Comment: This was exactly it. I added `SEPARATOR ' - '`  to the `GROUP_CONCAT` and it returned the text with dashes between. I think I just had it in mind that the separator should be applied to the concat not the group... okay I just confused myself then. I'm sure you're correct, I just need to think about it some more. Thank you @Arion !